# Azure container instances deployment failed

Tags: python, containers, azure-container-instances, azure-machine-learning-service

I am deploying a machine learning image to Azure Container Instances from Azure Machine Learning services according to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/tutorial-deploy-models-with-aml), but am always stuck with the error message:

> Aci Deployment failed with exception: Your container application crashed. This may be caused by errors in your scoring file's init() function.
>   Please check the logs for your container instance xxxxxxx'.

I tried:

1. increasing memory_gb=4 in aci_config.
2. I did
   [troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-troubleshoot-deployment#debug-the-docker-image-locally) locally, but I could not have found any.

Below is my score.py

```
def init():
    global model
    model_path = Model.get_model_path('pofc_fc_model')
    model = joblib.load(model_path)

def run(raw_data):
    data = np.array(json.loads(raw_data)['data'])
    y_hat = model.predict(data)
    return y_hat.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you registered the model `'pofc_fc_model'` in your workspace using the `register()` function on the model object? If not, there will be no model path and that can cause failure.

See this section on model registration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-deploy-and-where#registermodel

Comment: The answer is not clear. I have registered the model in to my workspace but still the error is perceived.