# Error in deploying model on azure kubernetes service

Tags: python, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-container-instances

I am deploying a model on Azure Machine Learning studio using azure kubernetes service

```
env = Environment(name='ocr')
aks_name = 'ocr-compute-2'
# Create the cluster
aks_target = AksCompute(ws, aks_name)




env.python.conda_dependencies.add_pip_package('google-cloud-vision')
env.python.conda_dependencies.add_pip_package('Pillow')
env.python.conda_dependencies.add_pip_package('Flask == 2.2.2')

env.python.conda_dependencies.add_pip_package('azureml-defaults')


inference_config = InferenceConfig(environment=env, source_directory='./', entry_script='./run1.py')

deployment_config = AksWebservice.deploy_configuration(autoscale_enabled=True, 
                                                autoscale_target_utilization=20,
                                                autoscale_min_replicas=1,
                                                autoscale_max_replicas=4)
```

I am getting this error

```
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": "Kubernetes Deployment failed",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "CrashLoopBackOff",
      "message": "Your container application crashed as it does not have AzureML serving stack.
Make sure you have 'azureml-defaults>=1.0.45' package in your pip dependencies, it contains requirements for the AzureML serving stack."
    }
```

Will be great if I can know what I am missing here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure container instances deployment failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55353889/azure-container-instances-deployment-failed)

Comment: No, we already have done this

Comment: and it also true that? "Make sure you have 'azureml-defaults>=1.0.45' package in your pip "

Answer (score 0):

When the packages which are required to run the pipeline are mentioned in the **requirements.txt**, we shouldn’t use the manual approach to update the pod with the libraries.

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

When the pod failed to find the library which is required from the requirements.txt it throughs  `CrashLoopBackOff` error based on the dependencies.

The dependencies must be available in the requirements.txt

**`azureml-defaults>=1.0.45`** -> install the package at **pod level** and include that in the **`requirements.txt`**